# MS SQL getting the sum of given date

Tags: mysql, database

Hi guys im having a hard time on how to get the sum of a given date in TotalSold column. I have here  PartNumber, TotalOrder, TotalSold and POUnitCost. How can i filter the date of TotalSold,since the date of it is located in another table named SO_SalesOrder. Thanks!

MyQuery:

```
select  PartNumber = (select name from base_product as PROD where prod.prodid = POL.prodid), 
        TotalOrder = sum(POL.quantity), 
        TotalSold = (select sum(SOL.quantity) from so_salesorder_line as SOL where SOL.ProdId = POL.prodid), 
        PoUnitCost = max(POL.UnitPrice)                      
from PO_Purchaseorder_line as POL
where POL.purchaseorderid in (
    select purchaseorderid 
    from PO_purchaseorder as PO 
    where orderdate >= '5/1/2015')
group by POL.prodid
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Looks like MySQL.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: hi its MsSQL maestro, i want also to filter the date of TotalSold

Comment: You mean that `so_salesorder_line` has a date column which shall be >= '5/1/2015', too?

Comment: yes sir. i have 5 tables BASE_Product for PartName, PO_PurchaseOrder for, OrderDate,PurchaseOrderID, PO_PurchaseOrder_Line for quantity, ProdId & PurchaseOrderID, SO_SalesOrder for OrderDate & SalesOrderID, and So_SalesOrder_Line for quantity, ProdId and SalesOrderID

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data and desired results. Also, decide if it's MySql or Sql-Server and remove the wrong tag.

Comment: @Christine: Then why don't you simply add `and SOL.orderdate  >= '5/1/2015'`?

Comment: Ok sir Zoha, im sorry im just new here i just really need help. Thank

Comment: @sir Thorsten where should put it?

Comment: Right after `where SOL.ProdId = POL.prodid` of course. Where else do you have `SOL` in your query?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  hi sir the OrderDate of TotalSold is in the SO_SalesOrder with Primary key SalesOrderId

Comment: You query looks a bit dubious by the way, because of the grouping containing the `POL.description`. What is a result row supposed to represent? A product (one row for a `base_product`)? Or an order of a product (one row per `PO_Purchaseorder_line`)?

Comment: Hi Sir @ThorstenKettner i've already changed the POL.description. Thank you so much for you help and GBU! :)

Comment: 'Sum of a date' is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP what do you mean sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `so_salesorder_line` with `so_salesorder` so as to be able to access the date.

By the way, use ISO date literals instead of ambiguous dates strings. ('5/1/2015' could mean May 1 or January 5 depending on the current setting in your DBMS.)

Here is the part to get the TotalSold (for the 1st of May - change this to '20150105' if you want the 5th of January instead.)

```
TotalSold = 
(
  select sum(SOL.quantity) 
  from so_salesorder_line as SOL 
  join so_salesorder SO on SO.salesorderid = SOL.salesorderid
  where SOL.ProdId = POL.prodid
  and SO.orderdate >= '20150501'
),
```

Comment: I'm glad it does :-) However, see my last comment to your request; the query doesn't look correct. The TotalSold refers to a product, but the POL.description refers to an order position. That seems queer. Your result rows should *either* be products *or* order positions.

Comment: Hi Sir I've notice that there's are still wrong in the results, I tried to revised it and i think ive got the right query. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think working with joins is much easier and clearer. Try this one:

```
    select po.orderdate, POL.description, 
    prod.name as PartNumber 
    sum(POL.quantity) as TotalOrder, 
    sum(SOL.quantity) as TotalSold, 
    max(POL.UnitPrice) as PoUnitCost                     
    from PO_Purchaseorder_line as POL
    left join so_salesorder_line as SOL on SOL.ProdId = POL.prodid
    left join PO_purchaseorder as PO on POL.purchaseorderid=PO.purchaseorderid
    left join base_product as PROD on prod.prodid = POL.prodid
    where po.orderdate >= '5/1/2015'
    group by po.orderdate, POL.prodid,prod.name
```

Comment: hi sir thanks. i also want to filter the date of TotalSold

Comment: @Djacks007: Working with joins is much more prone to errors in the first place :-) When working with aggregates from different tables, then join the aggregates not the tables. With a product having several records in POL and SOL for a date, you would multiply values and get incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

I revised it and got the correct result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
BASE_Product.NAME, 
BASE_Product.DESCRIPTION, 

TotalOrders = (Select(Select sum(quantity) from PO_PurchaseOrder_Line  as POL 
LEFT JOIN PO_PurchaseOrder PO ON POL.PurchaseOrderId = PO.PurchaseOrderId
        where POL.ProdId = BASE_Product.ProdId AND orderdate >= '20140101')),

PoPrice = (Select max(UnitPrice) from PO_PurchaseOrder_Line as POL where POL.ProdId = BASE_Product.ProdId ), 

PoExRate = (Select ExchangeRate from PO_PurchaseOrder where PO_PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId = POL.PurchaseOrderId) ,

UnitCost = (POL.UnitPrice) * (Select Round(ExchangeRate, 4) from PO_PurchaseOrder where PO_PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId = POL.PurchaseOrderId) ,

TotalSold = (SELECT SUM(SOL.quantity) FROM so_salesorder_line AS SOL 
   LEFT JOIN so_salesorder SO ON SO.salesorderid = SOL.salesorderid
   WHERE SOL.ProdId = BASE_Product.prodid AND SO.orderdate >= '20150101') 

FROM BASE_Product

FULL JOIN PO_PurchaseOrder_Line as POL ON BASE_Product.ProdId = POL.ProdId
```